# Idiom Request: What is the idiom that means "If it's hard/easy for you, it must be the same for others"?

Tags: idiom-requests

This is the situation: a younger brother just (badly) finished a rigorous exam and the older brother wants to say something that means "Others must feel the same, don't worry". Is there such an idiom?

Comment: You’re not alone? Wry, informal, probably outdated: Welcome to the NFL.

Comment: Also “We’ve all been there.”

Comment: "You're not alone" seems alright. "Welcome to the NFL" sounds like "Welcome to the real world", doesn't it?

Comment: "Welcome to the NFL" sounds a tad harsh unless "NFL" stands for something other than "No Free Lunch".

Comment: NFL = National Football League,

Comment: thanks, @Xanne and Lawrence, btw how can I upvote your comments?

Comment: Even the best fail.

Answer (score 0):

**In the same boat**

> Sharing a particular experience or circumstance with someone else.

*My sister failed her driver's test, and I'll be in the same boat if I don't practice parallel parking.*

[The Free Dictionary]